# How do I create a job in Rundeck to test a website login?

Tags: automation, jobs, rundeck

I am a beginner with Rundeck, I would like to create a job to test logins in a specific website.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [job](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/04-jobs.html#jobs) with an [inline script step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) that calls the site API using CURL.

For example, to test against rundeck itself you can use the following script inside a rundeck job:

```sh
curl -v -c cookie -b cookie -d j_username=admin -d j_password=admin http://localhost:4440/j_security_check \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    http://localhost:4440/api/38/system/info/
```

And the job definition, you can copy it and save it as a YAML file, then [import it](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/creating-jobs.html#importing-job-definitions) to your project to test.

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 2dc15b18-5b2c-4081-be72-17eb3618d68c
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Login
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        curl -v -c cookie -b cookie -d j_username=admin -d j_password=admin http://localhost:4440/j_security_check \
            -H "Accept: application/json" \
            http://localhost:4440/api/38/system/info/ | jq
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 2dc15b18-5b2c-4081-be72-17eb3618d68c
```